# In Mat paginator pageOptions is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

**- I'm trying to show data in table view using mat pagination.
 - The problem is [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" is not working.
 - Although, the next and previous are working perfectly.**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSortModule, MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-view',
  templateUrl: './sample-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-view.component.scss']
})
export class SampleViewComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['First_Name'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  constructor(private router: Router,private fs:patternService){
}
display_pattern(){

   this.fs.display_pattern(this.pattern).subscribe(
       (data) => {
         this.pattern = data.results;
         this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.pattern);
         this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
         setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
         console.log("Datasource:",this.dataSource)
       },
       err => {
         console.error(err);
       }

     );


   }




}
```

sample.component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" id=test>
             <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
               <ng-container matColumnDef="First_Name">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.First_Name}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
```

```
             </mat-table>
              <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [length]="50" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
          </div>
    </div>
```

**items per page dropdown is not showing. I checked in the console when I click the dropdown. I'm getting this error.
I'm using angular 8**

I need your help to fix this. Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you defined updateHub?

Comment: The paginator's length and size have to be set.

Comment: Yes, I've set the length and size, still not working <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [length]="50" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

Comment: No , I haven't @ArunMohan

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module.ts

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platformbrowser/animations';`

also add it to the imports array

`imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule]`